# Understanding the steps in making a counter for each letter when a sentence is inputed

Tags: binary-search-tree, bubble-sort, qbasic

I have an example of a program that shows how to set up a counter for how many times each letter of the alphabet was used. I don't understand the syntax of the middle portion of the program.

```
LET letter$ = MID$(sentence$, LETTERNUMBER, 1)
```

I have tried searching on youtube and tutorials online

```
CLS
REM Make Counters for each Letter!!!
DIM Count(ASC("A") TO ASC("Z"))
REM Get the Sentence
INPUT "Enter Sentence:", sentence$
LET sentence$ = UCASE$(sentence$)
FOR I = ASC("A") TO ASC("Z")
    LET Count(I) = 0
NEXT I

FOR LETTERNUMBER = 1 TO LEN(sentence$)
    LET letter$ = MID$(sentence$, LETTERNUMBER, 1)
    IF (letter$ >= "A") AND (letter$ <= "Z") THEN
        LET k = ASC(letter$)
        LET Count(k) = Count(k) + 1
    END IF
NEXT LETTERNUMBER
PRINT

REM Display These Counts Now
LET letterShown = 0
FOR letternum = ASC("A") TO ASC("Z")
    LET letter$ = CHR$(letternum)
    IF Count(letternum) > 0 THEN
        PRINT USING "\\##   "; letter$; Count(letternum);
    END IF
    LET letterShown = letterShown + 1
    IF letterShown = 7 THEN
        PRINT
        LET letterShown = 0
    END IF
NEXT letternum
END
```

A through Z appears with the count of how many times they appeared.

Comment: Sorry I didnt get what your question exactly is?

Comment: What does LET letter$ = MID$(sentence$, LETTERNUMBER, 1) do. Letter$ is replaced by the middle of the sentence? what are the letter number and 1 doing in the parenthesis as well?

Comment: Your code syntax seems to be correct and loads/runs well in qb64 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MID$ function returns a portion of a STRING's value from any position inside a string.

Syntax:

```
    MID$(stringvalue$, startposition%[, bytes%])
```

Parameters:

- stringvalue$

  can be any literal or variable STRING value having a length. See LEN.
- startposition%

  designates the non-zero position of the first character to be returned by the function.
- bytes%

  (optional) tells the function how many characters to return including the first character when it is used.

Answer (score 1):

Another method to calculate characters in a string:

```
REM counts and displays characters in a string
DIM count(255) AS INTEGER
PRINT "Enter string";: INPUT s$
' parse string
FOR s = 1 TO LEN(s$)
    x = ASC(MID$(s$, s, 1))
    count(x) = count(x) + 1
NEXT
' display string values
FOR s = 1 TO 255
    PRINT s; "="; count(s); " ";
    IF (s MOD 8) = 0 THEN
        PRINT
        IF (s MOD 20) = 0 THEN
            PRINT "Press key:";
            WHILE INKEY$ = "": WEND: PRINT
        END IF
    END IF
NEXT
END
```